# Issue with passing parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters, type-conversion

In my application following are getters/setters:

```
    private string client { get { return ClientText.Text; } set { ClientText.Text=value;} }
    private string application { get { return ApplicationText.Text; } set { ApplicationText.Text = value; } }
    private string starttime { get { return StartTimeText.Text; } set { StartTimeText.Text = value; } }
    private string stoptime { get { return StopTimeText.Text; } set { StopTimeText.Text = value; } }
    private string task { get { return TaskText.Text; } set { TaskText.Text = value; } }
    private string project { get { return ProjectText.Text; } set { ProjectText.Text = value; } }
```

I want to pass these 6 values to following,

```
Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entry=new Harvest_TimeSheetEntry(string,string,DateTime,DateTime,int,int);
```

How should I convert those 6 properties and pass to that function/constructor?

Comment: Do you want to pass values, or types? It's ambigious

Comment: I want to pass those 6 values which are mentiones but, their type should be as shown in the constructor.

Comment: using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

Comment: why have you made all the properties string, why startime,stoptime are not datetime and task and project as int

Comment: I think the question here is quite obvious. For those who think this is poorly explained, I would say it is your ability to understand the question that should be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking for exaclty, but *probably* you need something like:

```
var entry = new Harvest_TimeSheetEntry() {
    client = ClientName,  //CLIENT NAME YOU INTEND TO PASS TO CTOR
    starttime = startDateTime.ToString()  //DATE TIME YOU INTEND TO PASS TO CTOR
     .....
}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

**EDIT**

If the issue you face is converting from the `string` on UI to actual data type need to be constructed an instance of type, in this case you can use:

[DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ey1cdcx8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - to parse from string to `DateTime` format

and

[int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f02979c7.aspx) - to parse `integer` values.

Comment: `starttime` is defined as a string

Comment: @musefan: For this I call ToString() to assign it to a string property

Comment: pretty sure he wants the 6 string properties passing to the method he has defined. Hence, "How should I convert those 6 properties and pass to that function/constructor?"

Comment: My TimeSheetEntry() constructor defined somewhere with those type parameters. I'm getting values from textboxes. so all these are string values which I want to convert so I can pass those values to that constructor and would be able to create new entry.

Comment: @Dinesh: I updated my answer, check it out if this is what you're asking for.

Comment: @Tigran I want parameters inside the brackets of constructor.

Comment: @Dinesh: and you get them. Where is your problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way of converting would be to do this

```
DateTime dtStartTime = DateTime.Parse(starttime);
DateTime dtStopTime = DateTime.Parse(stoptime);
int intTask = Int32.Parse(task);
int intProject = Int32.Parse(project);
```

However, this assumes that the DateTime is in the correct format and that `task` and `project` are valid integers. You'll need to add your own error handling and a good way to do that would be to look in to the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) methods and [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method.

For example,

```
int intTask;
if(Int32.TryParse(task, out intTask))
{
    //parse successful
}
else
   //parse unsuccessful
```

Comment: Sorry. starttime,stoptime,task,project are all properties. You can't do this with properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a string to another data type then there are a few options you could use, and the methods available also depend on the target type. [(Worth a read)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4w53z0y.aspx)

The functions I would recommend in this instance are: [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

Here is an example of how to use each:

```
int convertedInt = int.Parse(myIntString);

DateTime convertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

You can then pass these values to your function.

NOTE: I have assumed your date format is `dd/MM/yyyy` - [others are available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

It is important to know that you well get an exception if either of the strings are not in the expected format. It is advised that your input fields are validated before calling these methods. It is also worth noting that there are `Try` methods available for each: [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) and [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx), which allow you to take action if the format is not valid.

Comment: Here my starttime and stoptime are string properties. I want to convert type of these properties. so, DateTime.ParseExact is not worked there.

Comment: @Dinesh: You are wrong, this will work fine. Providing you are within the same class as you have defined your properties as `private`